# Check if window has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the user has windows on focus, I'm currently doing this:

```
var isonfocus=true;  
window.onblur = function(){  
  isonfocus=false;  
}  
window.onfocus = function(){  
  isonfocus=true;  
}
```

And whenever I need to check if the user has the windows on focus I just do `if(isonfocus==true)`.

Problem: if the user loses focus before the page loads, even if I do 
`if(isonfocus==true)` it will return true, even though the window is not on focus, and defining the var to false `var isonfocus=false;` will do the reverse.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Imagine a PTC (Paid-To-Click) site, when you go and click an ad to view, most sites verify if the user is actually seeing the advertiser site (has focus) or not (lost focus).
This is similar with what I need, I need a way to verify if the user has the window (which contains an iframe) on focus.
And to gain focus, the user could click the iframe, document or on the tab.
And please note that this needs to work on all major browsers.

Comment: The correct answer must be : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var has_focus = true;

function loading_time() {
    $(":focus").each(function() {
      if($(this).attr("id")=="iframeID") has_focus = true;
    });

    if(has_focus==true) alert('page has focus');
    else alert('page has not focus');

    setTimeout("loading_time()", 2000);
}

window.onblur = function(){  
    has_focus=false;  
}  
window.onfocus = function(){  
    has_focus=true;  
}

$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout("loading_time()", 2000);
});
```

To make it more efficient, you need to `var has_focus = false;` and make the user click somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 94):

Use the [`hasFocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.hasFocus) method:

```
if (document.hasFocus()) {
  // ...
}
```

If you have `iframe`s on your page, they need to be checked separately:

```
function isFocused() {
  return document.hasFocus() || document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.hasFocus();
}
```

Comment: I need to check is the window has focus, not the document.

Comment: @user2536244 the documentation states "*Boolean value indicating whether the document or **any element inside** the document has focus*" - this will work for the window being focused as well.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if the window has an iframe (clicking on the iframe to gain focus).

Comment: Well that sounds correct to me as an iframe is supposed to behave as a separate window.

Comment: Using Chrome, it gave me two errors: Blocked a frame with origin "xxx" from accessing a frame with origin "yyy". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasFocus' of undefined

Comment: Ah that's Chrome's Cross Domain Request prevention kicking in - it would appear this approach wouldn't work for your particular scenario. You should maybe update your question so it's clear what your requirements are for other posters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656791/check-if-windows-page-document-iframe-has-focus

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`document.visibilityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState), which will be either `'visible'` or `'hidden'`, to know whether the page is in focus or not.

Comment: Not true, unfortunately. `visibilityState` is `visible` unless the page is completely off-screen because the window is minimized, the user is in a different tab in the same window, or the display is off. Simply being occluded by another window still counts as "visible."

Comment: In my case that's exactly what I needed and honestly when I read the question above, I believe that is the correct answer and it should be marked as such. There is no way with javascript to see if it is occluded by another window.

Comment: see my answer below if you want to know if the browser is the active/focused window

Comment: It looks like ```document.hasFocus()``` works on Windows, but does not work on Android if you switch into anoter app - the page still thinks it's in focus. So I had to use ```document.visibilityState == "visible"``` and it worked well on both in my case. Yours might be different.

Answer (score 1):

The information in this topic is too old.
Go ahead and use : `document.hasFocus()`.
Now it will work for every browser you'll need.

Browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about Opera support you might get better results using the `document.hasFocus()` method. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.hasFocus) for more info on that.

Comment: I need to check is the window has focus, not the document.

Comment: For Opera you should write a `hasHasFocus` function: `function hasHasFocus() { return typeof document.hasFocus === 'function'; }` I just think the name is funny.

Answer (score 0):

> **Cross Browser jQuery Solution!**
>   The following plugin will go through your standard test for various versions of IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.. and establish your declared methods accordingly. It also deals with issues such as:

- timers! ewwww!
- onblur|.blur/onfocus|.focus "*duplicate*" calls
- window losing focus through selection of alternate app, like word
- - This tends to be undesirable simply because, if you have a bank page open, and it's *onblur* event tells it to mask the page, then if you open calculator, you can't see the page anymore!
- Not triggering on page load

Use is as simple as:

```
$.winFocus(function(event, isVisible) {
    console.log("Combo\t\t", event, isVisible);
});

//  OR Pass False boolean, and it will not trigger on load,
//  Instead, it will first trigger on first blur of current tab_window
$.winFocus(function(event, isVisible) {
    console.log("Combo\t\t", event, isVisible);
}, false);

//  OR Establish an object having methods "blur" & "focus", and/or "blurFocus"
//  (yes, you can set all 3, tho blurFocus is the only one with an 'isVisible' param)
$.winFocus({
    blur: function(event) {
        console.log("Blur\t\t", event);
    },
    focus: function(event) {
        console.log("Focus\t\t", event);
    }
});

//  OR First method becoms a "blur", second method becoms "focus"!
$.winFocus(function(event) {
    console.log("Blur\t\t", event);
},
function(event) {
    console.log("Focus\t\t", event);
});
```

---

[<kbd>New</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>improved</kbd><kbd>version,</kbd><kbd>made</kbd><kbd>for</kbd><kbd>both</kbd><kbd>vanilla</kbd><kbd>and</kbd><kbd>jQuery</kbd><kbd>found</kbd><kbd>here!</kbd>](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery.winFocus/blob/master/winFocus.js)

---

```js
/*    Begin Plugin    */
;;(function($){$.winFocus||($.extend({winFocus:function(){var a=!0,b=[];$(document).data("winFocus")||$(document).data("winFocus",$.winFocus.init());for(x in arguments)"object"==typeof arguments[x]?(arguments[x].blur&&$.winFocus.methods.blur.push(arguments[x].blur),arguments[x].focus&&$.winFocus.methods.focus.push(arguments[x].focus),arguments[x].blurFocus&&$.winFocus.methods.blurFocus.push(arguments[x].blurFocus),arguments[x].initRun&&(a=arguments[x].initRun)):"function"==typeof arguments[x]?b.push(arguments[x]):
"boolean"==typeof arguments[x]&&(a=arguments[x]);b&&(1==b.length?$.winFocus.methods.blurFocus.push(b[0]):($.winFocus.methods.blur.push(b[0]),$.winFocus.methods.focus.push(b[1])));if(a)$.winFocus.methods.onChange()}}),$.winFocus.init=function(){$.winFocus.props.hidden in document?document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",$.winFocus.methods.onChange):($.winFocus.props.hidden="mozHidden")in document?document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange",$.winFocus.methods.onChange):($.winFocus.props.hidden=
"webkitHidden")in document?document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange",$.winFocus.methods.onChange):($.winFocus.props.hidden="msHidden")in document?document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange",$.winFocus.methods.onChange):($.winFocus.props.hidden="onfocusin")in document?document.onfocusin=document.onfocusout=$.winFocus.methods.onChange:window.onpageshow=window.onpagehide=window.onfocus=window.onblur=$.winFocus.methods.onChange;return $.winFocus},$.winFocus.methods={blurFocus:[],blur:[],focus:[],
exeCB:function(a){$.winFocus.methods.blurFocus&&$.each($.winFocus.methods.blurFocus,function(b,c){this.apply($.winFocus,[a,!a.hidden])});a.hidden&&$.winFocus.methods.blur&&$.each($.winFocus.methods.blur,function(b,c){this.apply($.winFocus,[a])});!a.hidden&&$.winFocus.methods.focus&&$.each($.winFocus.methods.focus,function(b,c){this.apply($.winFocus,[a])})},onChange:function(a){var b={focus:!1,focusin:!1,pageshow:!1,blur:!0,focusout:!0,pagehide:!0};if(a=a||window.event)a.hidden=a.type in b?b[a.type]:
document[$.winFocus.props.hidden],$(window).data("visible",!a.hidden),$.winFocus.methods.exeCB(a);else try{$.winFocus.methods.onChange.call(document,new Event("visibilitychange"))}catch(c){}}},$.winFocus.props={hidden:"hidden"})})(jQuery);
/*    End Plugin      */

// Simple example
$(function() {
 $.winFocus(function(event, isVisible) {
  $('td tbody').empty();
  $.each(event, function(i) {
   $('td tbody').append(
    $('<tr />').append(
     $('<th />', { text: i }),
     $('<td />', { text: this.toString() })
    )
   )
  });
  if (isVisible) 
   $("#isVisible").stop().delay(100).fadeOut('fast', function(e) {
    $('body').addClass('visible');
    $(this).stop().text('TRUE').fadeIn('slow');
   });
  else {
   $('body').removeClass('visible');
   $("#isVisible").text('FALSE');
  }
 });
})
```

```css
body { background: #AAF; }
table { width: 100%; }
table table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto; width: auto; }
tbody > tr > th { text-align: right; }
td { width: 50%; }
th, td { padding: .1em .5em; }
td th, td td { border: 1px solid; }
.visible { background: #FFA; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>See Console for Event Object Returned</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><p>Is Visible?</p></th>
        <td><p id="isVisible">TRUE</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Event Data <span style="font-size: .8em;">{ See Console for More Details }</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It fails to detect if user has switched windows using alt-tab.

Answer (score -6):

If the user has the browser window focused/active, but has just clicked the refresh button (or url bar, etc), `document.hasFocus()` will tell you the window is not active.

However, you can call `window.focus()` and see if the `focus` event is actually fired. If it is, the browser is still focused/active.

```js
const windowHasFocus = function () {
  if (document.hasFocus()) return true
  let hasFocus = false

  window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    hasFocus = true
  })
  window.focus()

  return hasFocus
}
```

Comment: Calling window.focus() will make a request to bring the window to the front. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus